# Installing Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, remote-desktop

I'm trying to install chrome Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but keep on getting the following error:

```
The package is of bad quality.
The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath.
Lintian check results for /home/sarahellen/Downloads/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64 (3).deb:
E: chrome-remote-desktop: dir-or-file-in-etc-opt etc/opt/chrome/
E: chrome-remote-desktop: dir-or-file-in-etc-opt etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/
E: chrome-remote-desktop: dir-or-file-in-etc-opt etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/com.google.chrome.remote_assistance.json
E: chrome-remote-desktop: dir-or-file-in-etc-opt etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/com.google.chrome.remote_desktop.json
```

Any help would be much appreciated: please note that I'm a Ubuntu newb!!

Comment: Did you do what that error says?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I'm going to try your suggestions and then I'll update the question after that

Answer (score 1):

You get such kind of errors when the package doesn't meet the [Debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html), then it is considered to be of a poor quality.

So a better way of going round this is to use the terminal to install it. So remove all traces of what you did and go through these steps:

`cd ~/Downloads` (or where the chrome remote .deb file is found)

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

where `*.deb` is for example "chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb"

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But make sure you have the dependencies installed for a clean installation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the terminal.

After entering the directory where you saved the .deb file, write:

`sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb`

and then

`sudo apt-get install -f`

It seems, anyway, that this problem exists since at least July 2014 ...